# How to split panes in Tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

I have recently installed `tmux` on my system and cannot get the terminal to split. I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> to split it, but nothing happens. I am most likely just overlooking something but help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using capital "b" with the Ctrl key?

Comment: The keystroke is CTRL-B, @GeorgeUdosen, not CTRL-SHIFT-B.

Answer (score 1):

According to the default key bindings you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> then release and press <kbd>%</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>) in order to split the panes vertically.

Also, make sure to check the file `~/.tmux.conf` if you have changed the key bindings.

You can also have a look at my `tmux` config [here](https://github.com/2KAbhishek/Dotfiles/blob/main/.tmux.conf) with more natural keybindings and some usability improvements.

Comment: This is a useful answer, since the reference to your config holds some extra value (I believe I used your config as base for my own `tmux` config a while back).